# Spring Transaction Aware cache is not working

Tags: java, spring, caching, ehcache

I am using spring cache abstraction using Ehcache as a cache provider.
I am trying to attach cache operations to spring JPA transactions, but not able to do so.

Even though transaction fails/rollback cache put happens.

Configuration,

```
        @Bean
    public EhCacheManagerFactoryBean cacheManagerUsingSpringApi() {
        EhCacheManagerFactoryBean ehCacheManagerFactoryBean = new EhCacheManagerFactoryBean();

        // provide xml file for ehcache configuration/
        ehCacheManagerFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("spring-cache-abs-ehcache.xml"));

        return ehCacheManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public org.springframework.cache.CacheManager ehCacheCacheManager() {
        final EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager = new EhCacheCacheManager(cacheManagerUsingSpringApi().getObject());
        ehCacheCacheManager.setTransactionAware(true); // Setting  transaction aware
        return ehCacheCacheManager;
    }
```

spring-cache-abs-ehcache.xml,

```
    <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"
         updateCheck="true"
         monitoring="autodetect"
         dynamicConfig="true">

    <cache name="EmployeeCache"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

EmployeeRepository,

```
    public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long>, CustomEmployeeRepository {
    }
```

Transactional Method,

```
    @Repository
public class EmployeeRepositoryImpl implements CustomEmployeeRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;

    // THIS METHOD SHOULD NOT PUT INTO CACHE WITH NEW NAME
    @Override
    @Transactional
    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "EmployeeCache", key = "#a0.id")
    public Employee customUpdate(Employee employee) {
        employee.setFirstName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        entityManager.merge(employee);

        // rolling back transaction 
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

        return employee;
    }
}
```

Test case(caller),

```
    @Test
public void testCustomUpdate() {
    // GIVEN
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setFirstName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    employee.setLastName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    final Employee savedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    // WHEN
    final Employee updatedEmployee = employeeRepository.customUpdate(savedEmployee);

    // THEN
    final Cache employeeCache = cacheManager.getCache("EmployeeCache");
    final Cache.ValueWrapper object = employeeCache.get(updatedEmployee.getId());
    assertNull(object);
}
```

Test Should succeed i.e spring should not PUT data into cache in method `employeeRepository.customUpdate` if transaction was rollback in that method.
But, spring puts data into cache even if transactions fails.
**NOTE:** Weird part is, if entry already exists in cache , then @CachePut does not updates entry in cache if transaction fails.

So, if I annotate `employeeRepository.save` with `@CachePut(cacheNames = "EmployeeCache", key = "#result.id")` then cache is not updated in update call.

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1: Use advice ordering,

Refer to:
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ordering

The below declaration will cause the transactional advice to be executed first and then the cacheable advice.

```
<tx:annotation-driven order="0"/>

<cache:annotation-driven cache-manager="ehCacheManager" order="1"/>
```

### Option 2: Annotating @Cacheable and @Transactional on different methods

You will see the code working if you call the @Cacheable annotated method from another method which is annotated with @Transactional. Both annotations i.e. @Cacheable and @Transaction on the same method won't help your cause unless you have advice ordering implemented. Please see below a crude implementation of your logic.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Employee customUpdate(Employee employee) {
        Employee mergedEmployee = updateHelper(employee);

        // rolling back transaction 
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();

        return mergedEmployee;
    }

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "EmployeeCache", key = "#a0.id")
    public Employee updateHelper(Employee employee)) {
        employee.setFirstName(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        //On a merge(...) call on the entityManager, the returned item is the managed 
        //instance
        return entityManager.merge(employee); 
    }
```